# Sending string to sub-activity with i.putExtra and displaying in textview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, textview

I started learning android development (Android Studio) recently and really enjoy it. I have tried to solve this myself, but I've come to the point where I need to ask for some help.

I'm working on this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#exercise-starting-activities

I suspect things go wrong at step 6.6 or 6.7.

I have a main activity and a sub-activity and my issue is that the i.putExtra data I send to the sub-activity is not displaying in the textview with the ID: displayintentextra

Here is my code:

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputforintent);

        String value = text.getText().toString();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        i.putExtra("Value1", "Check it");

    }
}
```

Sub-activity:

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }

        String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
        if (value1 != null) {

            TextView displayintentextra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayintentextra);
            displayintentextra.setText("Value1"); }

    }
}
```

Sub-activity textview:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayintentextra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Note: I'm not sure whether the TextView will display "Value1" or "Check it" if this code is fixed, but it is supposed to display "Check it". Right now, the TextView is empty when I run the app.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: use displayintentextra.setText(Value1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MainActivity, put `i.putExtra("Value1", "Check it");` before the line `startActivity(i);`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "Check it");
startActivity(i);
```

And in ResultActivity, replace the line `displayintentextra.setText("Value1");` with `displayintentextra.setText(value1);`.

```
if (value1 != null) {

            TextView displayintentextra = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayintentextra);
            displayintentextra.setText(value1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

In MainActivity, put i.putExtra() before startActivity method. Currently no bundle extras are passed to the ResultActivity since it is called before setting the extra string..

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "Check it");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, sJy! It makes sense why it didn't work then.